# Add Nowplayiing Functionality in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am creating video player app in iOS i am use MpMoviePlayer. All are working good.

My problem is, i want to add now playing feature in my app same like musi app here is link
https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/musi-unlimited-free-music/id591560124?mt=8

I was implement now playing features in my app but it not work smoothly.

Can you help me ya suggest me how to do it???

nowPlaying click btn Action

```
 @IBAction func nowPlaying(sender: AnyObject) {

    dataVideoName2.removeAll()
    dataAuthorName2.removeAll()
    dataVideoId2.removeAll()
     let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("player") as! SimpleplayerViewController

      vc.videoID = dataVideoId2
      vc.videoTitle = dataVideoName2
      vc.artist = dataAuthorName2
      vc.thumbURL = dataVideoThumb
      vc.dismiss = 1
    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Irshad,

You can add an NSTimer to your VIDEO to check the time on a regular basis.

```
func updateAVDTag() {
    let currentPT:Float64 = CMTimeGetSeconds((self.streamPlayer.player?.currentTime())!)
    let currentPlayerTString = String(currentPT)
    currentPlayerTime = String(currentPlayerTString.characters.prefix(4))
}

self.playingAV = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: "updateAVDTag", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

And a notification to tell you when it is finished.

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:   "finishedPlaying:", name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, object: playerItem)

func finishedPlaying(myNotification:NSNotification) {
   self.streamPlayer.view.removeFromSuperview()
    playingAV.invalidate()
    playingAV = nil
    print("VIDEO finished")
}
```

But be careful to make sure that any code to update the UI is running on the main thread and that your player is not a local variable. The code to ensure your running the UI update on the correct thread.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            // Update UI
    }
```

Comment: thanks for reply but can u give me more details about last portion